# How do I align a QWidget to the right of a QToolBar?

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbar

I have some QWidget (QLineEdit), and I would like to align it to the right of my QToolbar.

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting a spacer widget before it:

```cpp
QToolBar* toolBar = new QToolBar("Toolbar");

QWidget* spacer = new QWidget();
spacer->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
toolBar->addWidget(spacer);

// now add your actions or widgets after the spacer widget
```